# How can I target unchecked checkboxes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I uncheck any checkbox it also appends the result. I want to remove that. What should I do?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chk_val').on('click',function(){
        var result = $(this).val();
        $('#course').append(result);
    });
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show">
<span id="course"> </span>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="chk_val" value="20" />20
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk_val" value="30" />30
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk_val" value="40" />40
<br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.chk_val').on('click', function() {
    var result = $('.chk_val:checked').map(function() {

      return $(this).val()
    }).get();
    $('#course').html(result);


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show">
  <span id="course"> </span>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="chk_val" value="20" />20
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk_val" value="30" />30
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk_val" value="40" />40
<br />
```

1. Map the value of checked items.
2. Use `.html()` to change the html of the div